# How to give a developer (freelance) access to only one folder in our BITBUCKET?

Tags: git, bitbucket

We want to work with a new developer and we don't want to show him all the codes right away. This is the way we're working today:

1. Local GIT
2. PUSH to BITBUCKET
3. AUTO push to AWS EB (our test server).

Now we want to work with him this way:

1. He will get access to only one folder in BITBUCKET (we know they don't give this option.
2. He can PUSH to BITBUCKET to the folder we gave him access.
3. The AUTO push to AWS test server will happen.

Any idea how we can solve it? maybe there is a better software that could help us here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a folder in repo? You can't. But there are workaround to overcome that.

Comment: @khrm Yes I mean folder in repo, what is the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way you can control access to a folder in git. In other vcs like svn, you can. So what you can do is create a git submodule. And give access to that submodule repository.

First create a new repo containing only your new folder.(submodule)

```
git clone repo newfolder
cd newfolder
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter 'path to the folder that need to be added as submodule' --prune-empty -- --all
git remote rm origin
git remote add newgitrepoin.bitbucket
```

Now in original repo:

```
git rm 'path to the folder to be added as submodule'
git commit
git submodule add newgitrepoin.bitbucket "path to folder deleted above"
git submodule init
git submodule update
git add .gitmodules "path to folder deleted above"
git commit
```